# Without use trigger and function how to create automatic date partitioning in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-partitioning

Without use trigger and function how to create automatic date partitioning  in  PostgreSQL

Comment: some developer say that may be we can create  like scheduler , shell script, cron job, but i cant understand which is the perfect way

Comment: without use third party its possible or not

Comment: pg_partman is useful for the old-style trigger-based partitioning, but less so for declarative partitioning. Sure, it comes with a background process that schedules operations. But I'd rather not have a third-party extension and write a simple `crontab` entry.

Comment: Stop looking for "perfect way", there is no such thing.  Instead look for adequate and acceptable. Realize that what is the "perfect way" for your organization/application is forbidden in mine.